# Timestamp-based conflict resolution without reliable time synchronization

Tags: javascript, synchronization, timestamp, conflict

Let's take as an example a js "app", that basically does CRUD, so it creates, updates and deletes (not really) some "records".

In the most basic case, one does not need to resolve conflicts in such an application because the ACID properties of the DBMS are used to eleminate concurrent updates (I'm skimming over a ton of details here, I know). When there's no way to emulate serial execution of updates, one can use timestamps so determine whch update "wins". Even then the client need not worry about timestamps, because they can be generated at request time on the server.

But what if we take it one step further and allow the updates to queue up on the client for some unspecified amount of time (say, to allow the app to work when there's no network connectivity) and then pushed to the server? Then the timestamp can not be generated on the server, since the time when the update was pushed to the server and the actual time when the update was performed may vary greatly.

In the ideal world, where all the clocks are synchronized this is not a problem - just generate a timestamp on the client at the time when the update is performed. But in reality, time often drifts from the "server" time (which is assumed to be perfect, after all, its *us* configuring the server, what could ever go wrong with it?) or is just plain wrong by hours (possible when you don't set the time zone, but instead update the time / date of the system to match). What would one do to account for reality in such a case?

Perhaps there's some other way of conflict resolution, that may be used in such a case?

Comment: even in an ideal world of all clocks in sync, conflict resolution on queued updates is an unresolved issue. Users would get unexpected and unexplicable results. The only way to cope with this issue is to leave the update in a "pending" state and inform the user accordingly.

Comment: The example should be `allow the app to work when there's no network activity(idle).`

Comment: @user568109: This is _one_ example. The problem is a bit more general, than that

Comment: you can greatly improve the real-world reliability of a naive approach by syncing the client and server times. in short, you need a client-side function getServerTimeStamp() that works with or without connectivity. yes, you still have drift and DST, but you'll be a heck of a lot closer than just using the client time. beyond that, operational transforms are how google docs handles such problems, with aplomb.

Comment: There are some additional questions I think you need to consider: is your primary interest real time resource management, accounting, or something else? how important is accuracy?  how soon does convergence need to happen?

Comment: Instead of sending client generated timestamps, send length of the time the even was queued on the client side and let your server to calculate correct timestamp.

Comment: I don't think the type of client matters at all here. If you want to handle a situation where offline is acceptable for unlimited amounts of time, then you need a way to revert an unlimited stack of changes. I recommend setting some bounds...

Comment: @jnewman : you are correct wrt keeping an unlimited stack of changes, but this is a bit out of scope of the question. Of course, there are ways of dealing with it (indeed, you can not keep an infinite history), that are mostly specific to the synchronization algorithm, that is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has two aspects :

1. Synchronizing/serializing at server using timestamps via ACID properties of database.
2. Queues that are with client (delays which server is not aware of).

If you are maintaining queues at client which push to server when it sees fit, then it better have trivial synchronizing. Because it is just defeating the purpose of timestamps, which server relies on.

The scope of ACID is limited here because if clients updates are not realtime, it cannot serialize based on timestamp of request created than or request arrival. It creates a scenario where a request R2 created later than request R1 arrives before R1.

Time is a relative concept, using a local time for client or for server will cause `drift` for the other. Also it does not scale (inefficient if you have several peer nodes - distributed). And it introduces a single point of failure.

To resolve this [vector-clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) were designed. They are logical clocks that increment clock when event occurs on the machine atomically. BASE databases (Basically Available, Soft state, Eventual consistency) use it.

The result is that 1 and 2 will never work out. You should never queue requests which use timestamp for conflict resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Nice challenge. While I appreciated the [user568109](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18613296/412808)'s anwser, this is how I handled a similar situation in a CQRS/DDD application.

While in a DDD application I had a lot of different commands and queries, in a CRUD application, **for each type of "record"** we have CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE commands and a READ query.

In my system, on the client I kept track of the previous sync in a tuple containing: UTC Time on the Server, Time on the Client (lets call this **LastSync**).

**READ**
Read query won't partecipate to syncronization. Still, in some situation you could have to send to the server a LogRead command to keep track of the informations that were used to take decisions. Such kind of commands did contain entity's type, entity's identifier and LastSync.ServerTime).

**CREATE**
Create commands are idempotents by definition: they either success or fail (when a record with the same identity already exists). At sync time you will have to either notify the user of the conflict (so that he can handle the situation, eg by changing the identifier) or **to fix timestamp** as explained later.

**UPDATE**
Update commands are a bit trickier, since you should probably handle them differently on different type of records. To keep it simple you should be able to impose the users that the last update always wins and design the command to carry only the properties that should be updated (just like a SQL UPDATE statement). Otherwise you'll have to handle automatic/manual merge (but believe me, it's a nightmere: most users won't ever understand it!) Initially my customer required this feature for most of entities, but after a while they accepted that the last update wins to avoid such complexity. Moreover, in case of Update on a Deleted object you should notify the situation to the user and, according to the type of entity updated, apply the update or not.

**DELETE**
Detele commands should be simple, unless you have to notify the user that an update occurred that could have lead him to keep the record instead of delete it.

You should carefully analyze how to handle each of this command for each of your type of entity (and in the case of UPDATEs you could be forced to handle them differently for different set of properties to update).

**SYNC PROCESS**
The sync session should start sending to the server a message with

- **Current Time** on the Client
- **LastSync**

This way the server could calculate the offset between its time and the client's time and apply such offset to every command he recieve. Moreover it can check if the offset changed after the **LastSync** and choose a strategy to handle this change. Note that, this way, the server won't know **when** the client's clock was adjusted.

At the end of a successful sync (it's up to you to decide what successful means here), the client would update the **LastSync** tuple.

**A final note**
This is a quite complex solution. You should carefully ponder with the customer if such complexity give you enough value before starting implementing it.

Comment: While your answer contains valuable information, I've kinda sorta knew it already (basically, this is timestamp-based conflict resolution with a twist), while user568109's answer taught me something genuinely new to me (logical time concept). Thanks very much for the effort though, it's sad I can't reward you both. Sorry!

Comment: No problem, I've found user568109's answer very informative, even if it actually don't provide a pratical solution. I shared this just as a concrete solution that I've alredy put in production facing a similar problem. Actually, there would be a lot more to say, but I hadn't more time to explain the quirks that I had to cope with.